# Checking if two ids are identical

Tags: php, sql, algorithm

I've added a feature to a web site that shows what visitors have visited a user profile. The table representing this holds the id of the user profile and the id of user visiting the profile.

Obviously, it's pointless showing that someone has visited their own profile so I modified the PHP code to detect this. In the meantime, a bit of data was written. This isn't a problem because it represents only a handful of users and I can edit the information by hand.

My question is as follows. In the hypothetical case where I'd have to do the same thing for more data, what would be a good approach to finding rows where id1 = id2 and removing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE 
  FROM table
 WHERE id1 = id2;
```

Comment: Thanks Ronnis. Same comment as for harakiri's reply :)

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM `profiletracking` WHERE `visitor_id` = `profile_id`;
```

Comment: Thanks harakiri. I like one-liner answers. I'd forgotten that it's possible to use field names symbolically.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to delete it, harakiri's query is good but I have a question, why to add a record in the first place? In time your website could grow bigger and things might get complicated.

I would suggest you to not record it to the database in the first place. You just do more actions and queries while there is a shorter way.

```
<?php
// Get ID of profile owner;
/* do your query here */
if ($_SESSION['id'] != $profileOwner['user_id']) {
// add it to your database
}
?>
```

I believe such approach is more elegant and useful, considering in the future your web site might grow bigger and you might need to check your codes again.

Please don't forget such things might be headache. This is a fatal mistake for a programmer. In the beginning, many thinks, ok for now this do the trick, why to bother coding more? In time you will add more and more codes, later you might lose yourself in it. It will be too late once your visitors / customer will start to complain about slow opening pages, eventually bad coding.

Comment: Hi Pixeler. You bring up a good question. The reason for keeping ids is to display the users that have visited a profile. To limit the data each there is only one profile_id/visitor_id pair and only the timestamp is updated once the record exists. In PHP, I've added a check on !$ownprofile to avoid an extra query. Thinking about it now, it could generate a big number of permutations. I will add another question about this.

Comment: @James P. I still see keeping the record of profile owner is more work for web server. You still can update if the record exists if not create new one (if it is not the profile owner). Since you will be needing only id, using query to just grab the "id" of the member would take some work load from your server, considering such social projects etc, needs pretty big member table. Big projects needs extra attention while coding. If you are not careful with your codes, you might end up having many troubles. For starters you will use more memory due to more actions / variables / arrays etc...